# Problem with pandas using by a logic operator to check double information in a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following problem:

I want to check two columns. When is true, I want to delete once.

```
if df['Close'] == df['Adj Close']:
    df.drop(['Adj Close'],axis='columns',inplace=True)
```

Give me the error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I know the problem, but I don't know a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `equals` method:

```
if df['Close'].equals(df['Adj Close']):
    df.drop(['Adj Close'],axis='columns',inplace=True)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your really fast answer.